# Download vimeo video through its URL

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I am trying to achieve this for vimeo videos through C# code, but the file being downloaded is the HTML. Can someone tell me how to do this? Below you can find the two handlers I implemented. Both have the same behaviour that I already described.

```
        Handle.GET("/testDownload", (Request r) =>
        {
            Response response = 0;

            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile("https://player.vimeo.com/video/140308351", @"c:\binte\test");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalDictionary.errorLog.LogError("Error in test download handler : " + ex.Message);
            }

            response.Body = "success";

            return response;
        }, new HandlerOptions() { SkipMiddlewareFilters = true });

        Handle.GET("testDownloadVideo?url={?}", (string url, Request r) =>
        {
            Response response = 0;

            string fileName = "testDownload.mpeg";

            try
            {
                using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
                {

                    myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), fileName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GlobalDictionary.errorLog.LogError("Error in test download handler : " + ex.Message);
            }

            response.Body = "success";

            return response;
        }, new HandlerOptions() { SkipMiddlewareFilters = true });
```

**EDIT:** After some research, I think this is not possible to be done, unless I would be the owner of the video, and therefore able to use the API for that purpose. I will leave the question open though, one day this might change.

Comment: Thats usually because the file you download contains where and how to stream info, rather than the video itself.

Comment: That is downloading HTML. You would need to parse the HTML and look for video source URLs or investigate the Vimeo API.

Comment: thanks! I will investigate your suggestion @AlexK.